# Actual Chip Thickness Calculation for CNC Machine Endmills

Tags: machining, cnc

Have a look at this image:

[image]

this image is from: https://www.guhring.com/Tech/endmillcalc

I would like to know how the formula for the **"Actual Chip Thickness"** is done
In this case, it is 0.104

Using speeds and feeds for this tool:
https://www.guhring.com/ProductsServices/SizeDetails?EDP=9067370160000
(Using HPC-ROUGHING; Aluminium, Al-wrought alloys, Al-alloys)

I managed to replicate all the other formulas in my spreadsheet it's just this one I'm having an issue with. I would like to have this because it seems to affect the (actual) MRR

I have contacted the manufacturer and a CNC form with no luck so far
Maybe I should ask this in the Mathematics community if no one here knows?

Comment: The chip thickness is based on the depth of cut ie the rate the cutting edge is advanced into the material that is the pitch oif you think about a thread. 1 turn = 1mm etc

Comment: The "radial chip thinning" calculation recommends 0.16 FZ, the manufacturer recommends 0.13 Fz, but with a stepover of 3.2, the actual Fz is 0.104 (thats why the radial chip thinning says 0.16 so you can get your 0.13 for 3.2 ae). I want to know how they calculate the 0.104 to get the 'actual' MRR (for comparison reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically i found the answer I was looking for, I hope it helps someone else too

[image]